# Submit Google Form only when connected to specific wifi

Tags: google-forms

I currently have a google form and a sheet working together as an event tracker. But I wanted to have an option to allow submission only when people are connected to my wifi.

Is there a way to do that with script?

I couldn't find anything about this and the options on Form is quite limited!

Thank you!

Comment: I dont think it's possible to get wifi info in browser (because it's sandbox). But if you have time, you could try to embed the google form inside a handmade application, then check for wifi info could be possible.